# drag and drop in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I am currently developing an application in which a user is displayed a list in the form of a tableview. when the user selects a particular row, he/she can drag it to another row. When that happens an alert is displayed giving some specific information.Any idea as to how it can be done.?

What I am doing is that I am using gesture recognizers.When a particular row is selected, an image of the selected row is made which then is dragged to the specific table view cell.I am able to move the image but my problem is that if I dont put the imageView under a UIView, the dragging stuff does not happen.....

My dragging code is based on apple's [touches sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html) .

#### Update:

After trying for some time, I am able to almost implement this.I still have one doubt though.. I am creating an image of a cell once it is tapped.Then UIPanGestureRecognizer has been added to that imageView which it turn makes its movement possible .The only problem is how can I know on which cell the image has been dropped?

Answer (score 9):

you should implement:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which will return YES, and also implememt:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 //do whatever u want after row has been moved
}
```

and then call this function from tableView:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to enter to edit mode.

Comment: @Ratinho.....I dont have to show reordering of cells....rather I have to show drag and drop on a cell.When I implement the methods u have suggested, the cell which I have to drop goes up and it looks like a reorder....

Comment: oh im sorry, i didnt understand you well.

Comment: Did you ever implement this functionality?

Answer (score 7):

This is a sample of an application with cells drag-n-drop in UITableView using native methods of delegate and dataSource of UITableView.
https://github.com/coderDove/UITableView-Drag-n-Drop